# Update Inner Join Freeze

Tags: mysql, sql

For some reason, this `UPDATE` query hang forever. If I replace to `SELECT` - it get the result instantly.

```
UPDATE table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT count(*) as total, left(number,7) as prefix, outcome FROM table1
    where outcome like '%Passed%'
    group by prefix 
    order by total desc limit 200
) AS t2 
ON t2.prefix = left(t1.number,7) AND t1.outcome = 'Fail'
SET t1.outcome = '', t1.status = 'NEW'
```

What is wrong there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```
UPDATE table1
SET
  table1.outcome = '',
  table1.status = 'NEW'
WHERE
  outcome = 'Fail'
  AND 
  left(number,7) IN (SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT left(number,7) as prefix
    FROM table1
    WHERE outcome like '%Passed%'
    GROUP BY prefix 
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) desc limit 200
    ) s
  )
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/753c2/1).

Comment: I think you are missing `count(*)` ?

Answer (score 2):

Try to move the `ORDER BY` and `LIMIt` to the end of the `UPDATE`. Something like:

```
UPDATE table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT count(*) as total, left(number,7) as prefix, outcome FROM table1
    where outcome like '%Passed%'
    group by prefix 
) AS t2 ON t2.prefix = left(t1.number, 7) AND t1.outcome = 'Fail'
SET t1.outcome = '', t1.status = 'NEW'
order by total desc 
limit 200;
```

See the syntax of the [`UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html).

Comment: i was thinking about doing the same... but i am not sure, i think that the original query could replace more than 200 rows

Comment: @fthiella - I am not sure too, but, in this case it could be done in the `WHERE` clause using the predicate `IN`: `UPDATE ... WHERE prefix IN (... LIMIT) `

Answer (score 0):

Can you update the column on which you're joining? That is, `t1.outcome`.

Move the filter expression `t1.outcome = 'Fail'` out of the `JOIN` and in to a `WHERE` clause.

```
UPDATE table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT count(*) as total, left(number,7) as prefix, outcome FROM table1
    where outcome like '%Passed%'
    group by prefix 
    order by total desc limit 200
) AS t2 
ON t2.prefix = left(t1.number,7)
SET t1.outcome = '', t1.status = 'NEW'
WHERE t1.outcome = 'Fail'
```